# Book: boy meets a guy who gets killed, and escapes to a pocket dimension where inhabitants are versions of himself

Tags: story-identification, books

It was about this boy who meets this guy. Something happens where the guy is killed by bad guys as the kid escapes to a pocket dimension.

It turns out that the guy and all the inhabitants are versions of himself, old, young, male, female, even a few animals(?). He is an outcast here and few people want to be kind to him because the guy who died was a popular mentor. They fight evil.

The cover had a red-headed kid on it, with people in the background flying through the sky(?). Anyway, the cover stood out in my memory because it was really stylized and bright, almost like a comic book.

Answer (score 9):

*InterWorld* (2007) by Neil Gaiman and Michael Reaves?

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/47701.InterWorld):

> InterWorld tells the story of Joey Harker, a very average kid who discovers that his world is only one of a trillion alternate earths. Some of these earths are ruled by magic. Some are ruled by science. All are at war.
>  
> **Joey teams up with alternate versions of himself from an array of these worlds. Together, the army of Joeys must battle evil magicians** Lord Dogknife and Lady Indigo to keep the balance of power between all the earths stable.

The [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterWorld) has Joey meeting a guy called Jay, Jay dying and the other Joeys resenting the first Joey:

> Joey approaches it and as Joey tries to free the mudluff, a giant serpent (Revealed in the second book to be called a Gyradon) appears, biting Jay. **The mudluff kills the serpent but Jay was already dying.** Before he dies he gave Joey the direction to Base Town, where InterWorld HQ is. [...]
>
> **Many of the other Joeys initially resented Joey for causing Jay's death**, but soon come around about him as his skills improve.

And the cover has a red-haired kid and some flight-looking traits:

[image: book cover with redhead kid]

---

Found with the Google query `book "* dimension" "versions * himself" site:goodreads.com`.